# The view 'Index' was not found. Using vs2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-6.0

After reading the document of Visual studio 2019, and the .NET 6 has been released. The .NET5 would be out of support, So I changed my `.csproj`

```html
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```html
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

The problem is The `Index` can't be found on my subfolders even its in there. How do I resolve this issue? I removed also my `Startup.cs` and modified my `Program.cs`

Here's how my `Program.cs` looks like:

```js
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

app.Run();
```

Comment: You don't have to remove the Startup.cs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#apps-migrating-to-60-dont-need-to-use-the-new-minimal-hosting-model

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: No actually, I abandoned the project